# UINavigationController and low-memory warnings

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, nib, didreceivememorywarning

I use a UINavigationController (included in my app's main NIB file) with the following view-controller structure:

```
navigationController
        |
        V
      RootVC  --->  LevelOneVC  --->  LevelTwoVC
```

All my view controllers' views are loaded from NIB files using the same name as the view controller classes (RootVC.xib, etc).

**The problem:** 
When I push a LevelOneVC, then a LevelTwoVC onto the navigation stack, and *then* simulate/get a low-memory warning, the following happens: After popping the upper-most view controller (LevelTwoVC), when trying to pop the subsequently-current view controller (LevelOneVC), the Back button flies out to the right, but the RootVC's view does not appear.

It all looks as if, for the navigation controller, the RootVC is indeed now the current controller, but that "only" its view could not be re-loaded from the NIB file.

Any ideas as to why this might be happening?
Thanks!

Comment: I know this is months ago but did you find a solution? I've come across something similar and I'm going to try a few things, including just rebuilding the root view controller when it pops back to view.

Comment: Unfortunately, no we didn't. In the end we did away with the standard navigation bar, so it no longer mattered. I haven't managed to reproduce the strange behavior. If you find any clues, please do let me know.